# Connecting 5V arduino logic with 12V car logic

Tags: voltage

I need to connect arduino to K-Line in my car's OBDII port.
I used an L7805 to power the atmega but how can I interface 12V car logic with 5V arduino logic?
The problem is, the connection has to be bidirectional- sometimes the arduino 
will pull the line high/low and sometimes the car will - the purpose of 
this connection is to get throttle, rpm etc. data.
This would be easy if the connection was one directional - I could use a 
transistor to steer 12V to going IN the K-Line and voltage divider if I wanted to do the reverse. But how to do both?

Comment: [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Low-Cost-OBD2-Communications-on-K-line-ISO-9141-2-/) they use a voltage divider for the RX and a transistor for the TX.

Comment: These bi-directional logic level converters work with 5V and 12V, and cost 0.33CAD: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4-channel-IIC-I2C-Logic-Level-Converter-Bi-Directional-Module-5V-to-3-3V-For-Arduino/32310628741.html

Answer (score 1):

I found this that may be helpful to you.  this circuit allows for bidirectional communication between automotive K-line ECUs and an arduino.
 [K-Line Interface circuit](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=226474.0)